# C++ Win32 API Delete file with progress bar

Tags: c++, file, api, winapi, delete-file

Using the windows api, is there any way to delete a large file (lets say 1gb+), and monitor the progress somehow? I'm sure its possible but I have no idea where to start..

EDIT: Should have been more specific, I want to move the file to the recycle bin, and show a progress bar similar to explores, though I might want the progress bar in a console or something so I don't want an exact replica.

EDIT 2: Yeaah guess it is instant, should have tested before I asked the question.
Anyway to just close this question?

Comment: Are you really deleting it, or moving it to the recycle bin? Are you trying to show a progress bar identical to the one explorer shows for deletes?

Comment: What's the meaning of progress bar on deleting a file? It's an operation which is not dependent on the file size.

Comment: When you say delete, do you mean a secure erase?  Deleting a 1Gb+ file doesn't take any longer than deleting 1Kb file since most of the data in the file is untouched by DeleteFile()... you're really only changing metadata.

Comment: Re the edit - moving to the recycle bin is again an operation not dependent on the file size, it's a move within the hard drive - just reconnecting to another directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx) with the `FO_DELETE` func and `FOF_ALLOWUNDO` flag to move a file to the Recycle Bin. Progress will automatically be shown unless you also specify FOF_SILENT.

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileop = { 0 };
fileop.hwnd = hwndMain; /* your window */
fileop.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
fileop.pFrom = szFilePathToDelete;
fileop.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO /* | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION to recycle without prompting */;
int error = SHFileOperation(&fileop);
```

**Update:** As noted in the question edit, progress won't be shown for a single file, but it will be shown if recycling an entire directory. This also doesn't let you override the UI (e.g., to display progress in a console window).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could progressively truncate it using SetEndOfFile? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531(v=vs.85).aspx. Then removing the inode (or whatever it's called in Windows-land) could be quickly done.

[update]Just tested; the other guys are right. Removing the inode (delete) is instantaneous on a 1gb file.